# Linq XML won't select specified xml elements

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I'm trying to grab/select certain xml elements that are deeply nested in a .vcxproj file.
So far, I'm not having any luck. No matter what I do, my linq query is coming up empty:

```
private static void CheckProject(FileSystemInfo file)
{
    Console.WriteLine(file.FullName);
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file.FullName);

    var elems = from elem in doc.Descendants()
        where elem.Name == "Link"
        select elem;

        foreach (XElement elem in elems)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(elem.Name);
    }
}
```

I also tried this linq query, to no avail:

```
var elems = from elem in doc.Descendants("Link")
        select elem;
```

Comment: `.Descendants`? I only ever worked Elements - but I never got that deep into Xml or DOM for that matter.

Comment: I have used Linq and XML very rarely over the years. So I'm new too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compare the LocalName, not the [XName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.name.aspx).

```
var elems = doc.Descendants().Where(e=> e.Name.LocalName == "Link");
foreach (XElement elem in elems)
{
    Console.WriteLine(elem.Name.LocalName);
}
```